# Actual value from useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have my useState hook here:

`const [countOfItemsInOrder, setCountOfItemsInOrder] = useState(0);`

I call setState action in other component, and then I use it in object which goes to redux. And I have a problem. My useState value in redux is previous.

Here is my function with setSate. Function calls on click:

```
const onPressAdd = () => {
    setStateAction(prevState => prevState + 1);
    onAdd();
  };
```

I put setState action as a prop from other component. And then use object with state in my redux action:

```
const onAdd = () => {
    const totalPrice = servicesList.reduce(
      (sum, current) => sum + current.price,
      0,
    );
    const totalTime = servicesList.reduce(
      (sum, current) => sum + current.time,
      0,
    );

    const payload: OrderData = {
      id: 0,
      totalPrice,
      totalCount: countOfItemsInOrder,
      totalTime,
      name,
      services: servicesList,
    };

    dispatch({type: actions.order.addOrder.type, payload});
  };
```

So, for example, I click - on my screen value - 1, but in redux - 0. I click again, on screen - 2, in redux - 1. Can you help, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, so `countOfItemsInOrder` is not updated yet when you store it in Redux.

But, why do you have a `state` if you're storing this value in `redux`?
Just create an `action` which will add +1 to `totalCount`, and retrieve `countOfItemsInOrder` (which is `totalCount`) directly from redux.

You don't need an internal state in your case